# Trying to replicate rows in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, rep

```
v

  id a    b     c  d
1  1 1 Adam Smith 10
2  2 2 John  Bond 15
3  3 3  Sam   Ted 20
```

I issued the following command at the prompt.

```
> v1<-rbind(v,rep(c(4,5,"Deb","Jones",25),5))
```

I am trying to make a dataframe v1 from the dataframe v, where v1 should look like this:

```
> v1

  id a    b     c  d
1  1 1 Adam Smith 10
2  2 2 John  Bond 15
3  3 3  Sam   Ted 20
4  4 5  Deb Jones 25
5  4 5  Deb Jones 25
6  4 5  Deb Jones 25
7  4 5  Deb Jones 25
8  4 5  Deb Jones 25
```

But what I am actually getting is this:

```
> v1

  id a    b     c  d
1  1 1 Adam Smith 10
2  2 2 John  Bond 15
3  3 3  Sam   Ted 20
4  4 5  Deb Jones 25
```

Why is the row `"4 5  Deb Jones 25"` appearing only once in `v1`, instead of 5 times?

Newbie here. So please explain in simple english. All help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `rep` creates a vector with 5 copies of "4 5 Deb Jones 25" in a single line

Answer (score 3):

`rep` doesn't work that way -- it'll just concatenate the outputs into a vector, which looks like a single row to `rbind`. Then, `rbind` trims its inputs to match the shortest length row.

Instead, you could use `lapply` on a vector of with appropriate length (5) here, and return the row every time. `list_of_rows <- lapply(1:5, function(pass) list(4,5,"Deb","Jones",25))` This gives you a list of the rows. You can use `do.call(rbind, list_of_rows)` to turn that into a matrix with 5 identical rows.

You can wrap that matrix in a `data.frame`:

`df_tmp <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(1:5, function(pass) list(4,5,"Deb","Jones",25))))`

```
  X1 X2  X3    X4 X5
1  4  5 Deb Jones 25
2  4  5 Deb Jones 25
3  4  5 Deb Jones 25
4  4  5 Deb Jones 25
5  4  5 Deb Jones 25
```

While `df_tmp` looks ok, each column is actually a list, which is annoying to work with. You can fix this with `unlist`

```
df <-lapply(df_tmp, unlist)
str(df)

 List of 5
 $ X1: num [1:5] 4 4 4 4 4
 $ X2: num [1:5] 5 5 5 5 5
 $ X3: chr [1:5] "Deb" "Deb" "Deb" "Deb" ...
 $ X4: chr [1:5] "Jones" "Jones" "Jones" "Jones" ...
 $ X5: num [1:5] 25 25 25 25 25
```

Thanks @thelatemail for pointing out the issue with earlier solution using `c` instead of `list`

Comment: Be aware this coerces everything to character (and then a factor) - e.g. - check out the results of `c(4,5,"Deb","Jones",25)` - something like `setNames(data.frame(list(4,5,"Deb","Jones",25)), names(v))[rep(1,5),]` might be a translation to ensure that numeric data stays numeric.

Comment: You can avoid this by replacing `c` with `list` in the answer, but then the data.frame has list columns ... Oh but using `unlist` can fix that. Thx. I edited the answer

Answer (score 2):

You could also just pass a `list` object to fill the rows you want in `v`.

```
v[4:8,] <- list(4,5,"Deb","Jones",25)
# or without knowing the number of rows:
v[(nrow(v)+1):(nrow(v)+5),] <- list(4,5,"Deb","Jones",25)

#  id a    b     c  d
#1  1 1 Adam Smith 10
#2  2 2 John  Bond 15
#3  3 3  Sam   Ted 20
#4  4 5  Deb Jones 25
#5  4 5  Deb Jones 25
#6  4 5  Deb Jones 25
#7  4 5  Deb Jones 25
#8  4 5  Deb Jones 25
```

Where `v` was:

```
v <- data.frame(id=1:3, a=1:3, b=c("Adam","John","Sam"),
     c=c("Smith","Bond","Ted"), d=c(10,15,20), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```